# Underlying connection was closed in WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, iis, entity

I've got 2 tables from the same database. Just customers and orders tables.
I'm able to get customers from there, but when i'm trying to get orders i have exception.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceTransportException' occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll
>   Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.;"

My httpRunTime is:

> httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="1048576" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647"/>

And this Error:

> Error: Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation

Comment: The problem was in amount of data in these tables. Second table has too many fields to get, i used LinQ to take them partially.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is happening:

1. A PREVIOUS SERVICE CALL HAS CAUSED AN EXCEPTION AND THE CONNECTION    HAS FAILED.  Service calls should in most cases not throw exceptions but rather return error results
2. the connection has timed out. Check closetimeout, sendtimeout, receivetimeout. see [Setting    WCF Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding)